# NoReverseMatch at /polls/　Why does error happen at line 0?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I am making a web site by seeing Django tutorial.I got an error,
NoReverseMatch at /polls/
Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name. It was told like

```
Error during template rendering
In template /Users/xxx/djangostudy/templates/base.html, error at line 0
Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I really cannot understand why error happens at line 0. 
base.html(it is in template folder) is

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">Tutorial</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="{% block nav_polls %}{% endblock %}"><a href="{% url 'polls:index' %}">polls</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">admin</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
    {% bootstrap_messages messages %}
    {% block contents %}{% endblock %}
    </div><!-- /.container -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.html(it is in polls) is

```
{% extends "polls/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block contents %}
  <table border="1" class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
          <th>質問内容</th>
          <th>公開日</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
          {% for question in questions %}
      <tr>
         <td>{{ question.question_text }}</td>
         <td>{{ question.pub_date }}</td>
         <td><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.pk %}">詳細画面へ</a></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  </table>
{% endblock contents %}
```

'detail' means detail.html,it is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'poll_vote' question.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
</html>
```

I think error message means index.html cannot load detail.html.So, i wanna do so,but I do not how to do it.Sould I write something at line 0 in index.html?

views.py in polls is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from .models import Question
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,redirect
from .models import Choice
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .forms import MyForm
from .forms import VoteForm
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url



# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'polls/index.html',{
        'questions': Question.objects.all(),
    })

# def detail(request,pk):
#     obj = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
#     if request.method == "POST":
#         form = VoteForm(question=obj,data=request.POST)
#         if form.is_valid():
#             form.vote()
#             return redirect('polls:results',pk)
#     else:
#         form = VoteForm(question=obj)
#     return render(request,'polls/detail.html',{
#         'form':form,
#         'question': obj,
#     })

def vote(request,pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError,Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request,'poll/detail.html',{
            'question':question,
            'error_message':"You didn't select a choice",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return redirect('index')
    return redirect('poll_results', pk)
    # pass

def results(request,pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'polls/results.html',{
        'question':obj,
    })

class FormTest(FormView):
   form_class = MyForm
   template_name = 'polls/form.html'
   success_url = reverse_lazy('polls:index')
form_test = FormTest.as_view()

class Detail(SingleObjectMixin,FormView):
    model = Question
    form_class = VoteForm
    context_object_name = 'question'
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['question'] = self.object
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.vote()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return resolve_url('polls:results',self.kwargs['pk'])

detail = Detail.as_view()
```

urls.py in polls is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from . import views

app_name="polls"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='poll_detail'),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/vote$', views.vote, name='poll_vote'),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/results$', views.results, name='poll_results'),
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^form$', views.form_test),
]
```

Directory is
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a typo:

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.pk %}">
```

to

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:poll_detail' question.pk %}">
 <!--                 ^^^^^^^  -->
```

Answer (score 2):

`{% url %}` takes in the **name of a URL** defined in `urlpatterns`, ultimately corresponding to a view. It's not about whether or not `detail.html` exists, you can't link directly to `detail.html` because you need a view that says how to render it.

Use `{% url 'poll_detail' ... %}` since that's how you've named your view.

See the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.pk %}">詳細画面へ</a></td>
```

You must modify urls.py in djangostudy to use

Specify namespace as specified in urls.py or use the name " poll_detail " specified in polls/urls.py

Please note that polls:This is designated as namespace and poll_detail is specified by name.